# Font Awesome Icons are not appearing in my csHtml

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, font-awesome

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<br /><br />
<h1>Help & Documentation</h1>

<ul>
    <li><i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i><a href="~/pdf/HowToSaveFilesiOS.pdf">How To Save Your Completed Enrollment Form on iPhone or iPad</a></li>
    <li><i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i><a href="~/pdf/HowToCheckEmail.pdf">How To Check Your Email.</a></li>
</ul>
```

I do not see any icons.

In my Layout.cshtml

I have a link in the header

```
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The icon seems to be available in Font Awesome Version 5. You may replace it with version 5’s CDN in the header.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/v4-shims.css">
```

And below is my test result:

[image]